# Can you send a file from a webpage via e-mail

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ironically, for an IT contractor, I find myself building a website for a recruitment consultancy.

They would like a form which allows users to send them a CV but, from a security point of view would like the CV's sent to an e-mail address rather than stored on a web server. Does anyone know if such a thing is possible with jquery forms plugin or some other type of script?

No luck so far with google etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html) page explain everything from file upload to sending email with attachment

Comment: Cheers, knew it was out there somewhere!

Comment: And when "this" page disappears off the web, this answer will be completely useless.  You really ought to include a summary of the page to which you are linking so that the answer has a life independent of the link.

Comment: Thanks @tvanfosson, very important point, I'll make it CW, Please feel free to edit it and I will try to add some later too. And btw there is no such question here before in SO? I just don't want to be duplicated one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email with attachment';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the upload proceed as normal into a temp folder on the web server, then email that file where it needs to go and then delete it.

Otherwise, it's just tell the user to email in their CV. I can't think of any way of redirecting the file stream into a mail message directly.